# Can I search decomposed forms of Hangul?

Tags: regex

I need to find constituents of Hangul characters. E.g. I'd like to find ㅏ in 한. Is there a way of doing it with Perl-compatible regular expressions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Unicode block](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#block) `\p{InHangul_Compatibility_Jamo}` (U+3130 - U+318F).

Python 3.x example (using third-party [`regex`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) module):

```
>>> import regex
>>> regex.findall(r'\p{InHangul_Compatibility_Jamo}', '한ㅎㅏㄴ글')
['ㅎ', 'ㅏ', 'ㄴ']
>>> regex.findall(r'[\u3130-\u318f]', '한ㅎㅏㄴ글')
['ㅎ', 'ㅏ', 'ㄴ']
```